# What is the best way for the user to close numerical keyboard in iOS in Flutter app?

Tags: ios, flutter, user-experience

I am working on a Flutter app. A problem I encountered is that there is no default "Done"- or "Close" button for the numerical keyboard on iOS.

I made an ok solution where the user can close the keyboard by tapping outside the keyboard or swiping downwards. But the ideal solution would be to have a "Done" button in the bottom right corner of the keyboard like Android does right?

I tried the following package [keyboard_actions](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions). But it was very buggy in my app. When the keyboard appeared it pushed up the text in the text field.

Why didn't Apple add a default "Done" button for the numerical keyboard? How do you solve this in the simplest and best way?

Thanks!

Comment: I think there is an option wherein you can change the value of that to done. You just have to find it out in the docs

Comment: Is your issue that you want the user to be able to close the keyboard once they are done entering a value, or that you want to have specific button called "Done" on the keyboard?